# Creating a uid by taking certain characters from gravity form fields

Tags: wordpress

Very new to wordpress hosting, I am not able to create a uid the way I want - Take 2 chars from field1, take another 2 from field 2 and so on...
It's all about the drag-drop fixed things in basic shared hosting, so I am looking towards a plugin.
Is there a free plugin that would let me do that?
Would deeply appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: What have you tried to do? Can you post your code?

Comment: Thanks for replying sir, I am not allowed to code anything there. Shared basic hosting. Am just using the templates and plugins.

Comment: I don’t think there’s a plug-in that will do it for you. You would need to write some code to make it work @lmao